# php laravel - how to pass controller output to view as iframe source

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller which gives output as URL , now I want to pass the output url to view and below is the code.But when I load the view I found that iframe is not loading and the url is showing in the body of the html.

inside controller this is how I am returning the output

```
 return view('ifr',['name' => $url]);
```

And this is my view code

```
<iframe src={{$name}}></iframe>
```

Could you please help me with the correct syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of
`<iframe src={{$name}}></iframe>`

Try
`<iframe src={!! $name !!}></iframe>`

More at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade / Displaying Unescaped Data

Answer (score 1):

Pass the iframe src in single quotes

Like

```
$src = '"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhierensolanki%2Fposts%2F1264241026994313&width=500" width="500" height="608" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"';

return view('welcome',compact('src'));
```

And in your view file.

```
<iframe src=<?php echo $src; ?>></iframe>
```

It will work.

Comment: still the url is printed in body of html page and iframe is null

Comment: I tested this code. It's work for me. can you give me your URL?.

Comment: You have Blade built into Laravel so use {!! $src !!} not <?php echo $src; ?>
(By the way you have an extra ">" after your php close tag)